# Script for Pre Input Values for Forms for Third party website

Tags: javascript, php, passwords

I need some setup for Automatic Fill User ID, Password and One Select Radio Button.

I am Environment consultant. and i have near 1k to 1.5k numbers of User ID and Passwords of my clients.
I use these all user ids and passwords on this website link - http://pbocmms.nic.in/OCMMS-0.1/

Is it possible that i click on a link or any type of bookmark or dragdrop and then automatic open this webpage and Select Industry Radio button and then Fill User ID and Passwords except Captcha Value.

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: FYI the captcha is easy to break as well, with a simple threshold, and OCR. Automating the whole thing should be simple enough, but way beyond the scope of a SO question unfortunately.